# Dependants of ancestral visa

Tags: united-kingdom, immigration

I was hoping someone could help me , I am currently applying for my ancestral visa and I am stuck on which visa type and sub type to choose on the visa4uk site for my kids . For my husband I choose reason for visit work , visa type work non points based and sub type dependant more than 6 months . Which options should I choose for my kids both under the age of 11 .
Thanks 
Tarren

Comment: Is there a reason for visit option for ‘Dependent’?